# Select last element of class

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make an article page where the article is partially visible.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="article col col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="articleTitle">Your Karate "Blocks" Are Dysfunctional. Here's Why.</div>
  <div class="articleAuthor">
    <p><a href="http://www.karatebyjesse.com/karate-block-real-meaning/" target="_blank">Jesse Ankamp</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <article class="preview">
    <p class="italic bold">

      “Traditional Karate blocks don’t work against real attacks.”
    </p>
    <p>That’s something I often hear.</p>
    <p class="italic">

      (Especially from people who don’t practice Karate.)
    </p>
    <p>They claim our Karate blocks require too much strength, power, speed, intuition and effort to successfully work against an opponent attacking full force.</p>
    <p>I agree.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="full">
    <p>Some more text</p>
  </article><a class="seeMore btn btn-primary">See More...</a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

I'd like to click on the see more button and have jQuery select the previous .full class. I'm just not advanced enough in selectors to know how.

Comment: why not use .seeMore class?

Comment: $('seeMore').click(function(){ $(this).prev().doSomething() });

Comment: Because I am going to have multiple articles on this page. I need to select the last one.

Comment: $('.classname:last')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something along the lines of this:

```js
$(".seeMore").click(function(){
   $this = $(this);
   $this.prev().toggle();
   $this.text( $this.prev().is(':visible') ? 'See Less...' : 'See More...')
});
```

```css
.full{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article col col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="articleTitle">Your Karate "Blocks" Are Dysfunctional. Here's Why.</div>
  <div class="articleAuthor">
    <p><a href="http://www.karatebyjesse.com/karate-block-real-meaning/" target="_blank">Jesse Ankamp</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <article class="preview">
    <p class="italic bold">

      “Traditional Karate blocks don’t work against real attacks.”
    </p>
    <p>That’s something I often hear.</p>
    <p class="italic">

      (Especially from people who don’t practice Karate.)
    </p>
    <p>They claim our Karate blocks require too much strength, power, speed, intuition and effort to successfully work against an opponent attacking full force.</p>
    <p>I agree.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="full">
    <p>Some more text</p>
  </article><a class="seeMore btn btn-primary">See More...</a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

---

**If your content is loaded dynamically, you'll need a slight tweak:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".seeMore", function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.prev().toggle();
   $this.text( $this.prev().is(':visible') ? 'See Less...' : 'See More...')
});
```

---

**If your HTML layout changes, but you will always have one "see more" button with each "full" element, this approach would work better:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".seeMore", function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var cur = $('.seeMore').index($this);
   $('.full').eq(cur).toggle();
   $this.text( $('.full').eq(cur).is(':visible') ? 'See Less...' : 'See More...')
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do! And fortunately my content is static so it should be good! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you need.

```
$(".seeMore").click(function(){
   alert("See more has been clicked");
   console.log($(this).prev('.full'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To select the last element having class **full** ,

```
$('.full').last();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.seeMore').on('click', function(){
        var fullClass = $(this).prev().html();
        alert(fullClass);
    });

});
```

I guess this may help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/nbq7prcr/

Answer (score 0):

> The :last selector selects the last element.

Note: This selector can only select one single element. Use the :last-child selector to select more than one element (one for each parent).

```
$('.classname:last')
```